# What does the following line do in makefiles?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What does this line do in makefiles?

```
-include Makefile.add_exp430.defines
```

Is Makefile.add_exp430.defines one file or is it a complexity of multiple files?
What is the minus prefix of include for?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Source 1:*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html)

> The `include` directive tells make to suspend reading the current
>   makefile and read one or more other makefiles before continuing

[*Source 2:*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html)

> To ignore errors in a recipe line, write a `‘-’` at the beginning of the
>   line’s text (after the initial tab). `The ‘-’` is discarded before the
>   line is passed to the shell for execution.

Say your Makefile is:

```
-include some_inexisting_file
all:
    @echo "Yellow!"
```

Running `make all` will output `Yellow!`

Without dash, the output becomes:  `Makefile:2: some_inexisting_file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Shouldn't the dash be placed preceding the include instead of the file to be included? -include inexisting_file instead of include -inexsisting_file?

Comment: Just to be clear, source #2 doesn't really apply here since `include` is not a recipe line.  However the dash before `include` is sort of similar to the dash before a recipe line, in that it allows make to continue to run after an error (of some type).